# Mapping a User entity into a User DTO in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dto

I'm developing a web app that contains a `User` entity that is derived from .NET Core's `IdentityUser`. Lets suppose there is another entity called `Comment` which has a relation to a user (the user who posted the comment):

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string SomeExtraField { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{

    //Owner (Creator) of the feedback
    public User User { get; set; }
    //body of the comment
    public string Body { get; set; }    
}
```

Now suppose I have an API endpoint that returns all of the comments in the system. If I query for all comments and include the User relation, when the object gets serialized, everything in the User class is serialized and sent to the client (including the users hashed password, etc). Obviously I don't want this. So I've created a `CommentService` layer that grabs the `Comments` from a `CommentRepository`. From my understanding, the service layer should do the job of mapping the raw `Comment` object into a Comment DTO, which only contains data that should be sent to the client. I've defined a comment and user DTO like this:

```
public class UserOutput
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeExtraField { get; set; }
}

public class CommentOutput
{
    public UserOutput User { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my service layer I have something like the following:

```
//Fetch all comments
var list =  await _repository.ListAsync();

//Map comments to DTO
var result = list.Select(x => new CommentOutput
{        
    Body = x.Body,
    User = new UserOutput
    {
        Id = x.User.Id,
        SomeExtraField = x.User.SomeExtraField,
    }
});
```

This all seems to work great. However I can foresee one problem. Lets say I have a large system with Comments, Posts, Likes, Private Messages, etc. I can map them all in a similar fashion above. Then one day I decide to add another field to the UserOutput DTO. Now I have to go through potentially hundreds of mapping code like the sample above to map the new field properly, and whats worse is the compiler wont tell me if I've missed anything. I would like to have a function somewhere that maps a `User` to a `UserOutput` but I don't know where it should go.

I've seen some suggestions to put a constructor to the DTO that does the mapping:

```
public class UserOutput
{
    public UserOutput(User user)
    {
        Id = user.Id;
        SomeExtraField = user.SomeExtraField
    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeExtraField { get; set; }
}
```

but I've seen people against this because it tightly couples the DTO with the Entity. I've also seen suggestions of using Auto Mapper but is also seems an equal amount of people are against it.

Where should I place code that can perform these DTO->entity and entity->DTO mappings so I don't repeat myself all over the place?

Comment: What is the stated downside to AutoMapper<>? IMO you write it in ToXXX() methods or that.

Comment: What if you could assign a User instance to a UserDTO instance like _usrOut = _usr_ and this will 'implicitly' convert the _usr_ in a _usrOut_? [Implicit keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit)

Comment: @Steve I would still have to define the implicit operator in the UserDTO which would need to reference the User entity. That would end up in the same coupling as just defining a constructor in the DTO that accepts a user doesn't it?

Comment: I believe Automapper can at least tell you if any fields are unmapped via the `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` call.

Comment: @Brad you could wrap the implicit method as well the constructor with the User parameter inside a _#if_ pragma and remove altogether the presence of the User object to the apps that don't need to know about its existence. Of course it would be even better if you keep the two object models in two different assemblies and deploy the DTO assembly to the external apps while keeping the complete model in use just to the internal service.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check out [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).
This library will help you to map the Entity Class into the ViewModel.

The way to use it is pretty straightforward.